# c# mvc - Downloading huge files hangs web application

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a feature that allows user to download files from server by clicking on the fileName on the web page. I am using ASP.Net MVC5. Downloads of any size (tried upto 2GB) works fine with my current implementation. The problem is when downloading files that are >200MB, web application hangs until the complete download is finish.

**Current implementation:**
When User clicks on fileName in a grid, it triggers the 'Download' ActionMethod that is in 'DocumentController' and thus the file is downloaded from server.

Then 2 approaches came to my mind to fix the above problem:

**Approach1**: Using Async feature. I am newbie to async programming. So could you please update my code below to behave asyn if this is the best approach.

```
 public ActionResult Download(string filePath, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                filePath = Path.Combine(baseUrl, filePath);
                string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);

                TransmitFile(filePath, fileName);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { }
        return Content("");
    }

    private void TransmitFile(string fullPath, string outFileName)
    {
        System.IO.Stream iStream = null;

        // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];

        // Length of the file:
        int length;

        // Total bytes to read:
        long dataToRead;

        // Identify the file to download including its path.
        string filepath = fullPath;

        // Identify the file name.
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath);

        try
        {
            // Open the file.
            iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);


            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = iStream.Length;

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + outFileName + "\"");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", iStream.Length.ToString());

            // Read the bytes.
            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read the data in buffer.
                    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

                    // Write the data to the current output stream.
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data to the output.
                    Response.Flush();

                    buffer = new Byte[10000];
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                }
                else
                {
                    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (iStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                iStream.Close();
            }
            Response.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Approach 2**: Ajax call to 'Download' ActionMethod. This did not work as well for me.

```
function downloadFile() {    
var data = //Gets data object using some action and works fine

$.ajax({
    url: '/Document/IsFileExistOnServer',
    data: { 'filePath': data.path },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (isFileExist) {
        if (typeof isFileExist != "undefined" && isFileExist != null) {
            if (isFileExist == "true") {
                window.location = '@Url.Action("Download", "Document", new { filePath =' + data.path + ', fileName =' + data.name + ' })';                    
            }
            else {
                alert("File Not found. Cannot download");
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error occured. Please try again.")
    }
});
```

}

The problem with ajax call is, the View that is requesting the File to Download is associated with another Controller (HomeController) and on clicking download, current page is getting redirected to a link like this:
http://localhost:59740/Home/Details/@Url.Action(Download,Document,new {filePath=2017/05/TestFile.db,fileName=test1Gb.db})

Please can someone help me with a best way to do this. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Does your application have a requirement to process that download within code, or could you just provide a "direct" link to the file of  `http://localhost:59740/2017/05/TestFile.db`?

Comment: The requirement is to process the download within the code. The file storage server is different to the application server, thus I think, I can't use a 'direct' link like that.

Comment: Would your IT person be able to set up a `virtual directory` to that file server?

Comment: I need to check with him. If he says Yes: What changes should I make to my code and If he says No: There isn't any other way to do this?

Comment: @MadMyche: Your idea isn't impossible, but it adds a notable constraint of requiring public access to those files. That is a BIG assumption to make and by no means automatically the case for OP. Download handlers have existed since the early days of ASP.Net, there is no reason to go against this well established feature.

Comment: @Flater I look at all options to answer the problem. Not all answers are code; some are infrastructure, others are architecture,  and yet there could be planning or standards involved.

Comment: @MadMyche: Suggesting OP shares all files via Google Drive would also be an option then, but completely beyond the scope and intention of a StackOverflow question. Your solution requires OP to make files publically available, which basically shuts out the application layer that OP is developing to serve said files to the user. I'm not arguing that your solution must be in code, I'm arguing that your proposed solution adds more requirements to the solution that OP (and his company) might intend or want for security or privacy purposes. E.g. public URLs do not check the user account privileges.

Comment: @Flater And I'm not arguing that it is the best solution either; what I am suggesting is that there is a dialogue within the organization to figure it out.

Comment: @Flater: I tried the out of box MVC File handlers to download and they work fine for small sized files but coming to larger files (> 500MB) they result in OutOfMemory Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this one:

`Response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, length);`

instead of this:

`Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);`